# Pytorch - training on a subset of class labels, does it affect testing accuracy?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Is it possible to train a neural network using a subset of class labels?
For eg, I have a set of cifar10 images and I intend to train on [0-3,4-6,7-9] class labels, will it affect testing accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

obviously --if you measure accuracy over the full set of labels-- as your network will never be able to predict unseen classes reliably